# Java with OpenCV failed to read PNG image

Tags: java, opencv, unicode, png

**SOLVED & WHY**:

Path to image contains Unicode character, I have to say it's a bug.

**ORIGINAL POST**:

I am new to OpenCV and just use java with OpenCV 3.2.0, 3.1.0, and 2.4.3 to read this image without any success, namely, no width or height can be read, though my aim is to find the harris corners, and use other image is without this problem.

**code**:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
public class Test 
{

public static void main (String []args)
{
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Mat img_object = Highgui.imread("E:/ℤIMAGEℂ/ℤtestℂ.png");
    System.out.println(
            "img_object.width() = " + img_object.width() 
            + ",\n img_object.height() = " + img_object.height()
            + ",\n img_object.depth() = " + img_object.depth()
            + ",\n img_object.channels() = " + img_object.channels()
            + ",\n img_object.total() = " + img_object.total()
            + ",\n img_object.type() = " + img_object.type()

    );
    }
}
```

**Image**:

[image]

**error**:

```
img_object.width() = 0,
img_object.height() = 0,
img_object.depth() = 0,
img_object.channels() = 1,
img_object.total() = 0,
img_object.type() = 0
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (code) in cv::imencode, file           ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp, line 430
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException:    cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp:430: error:    (-215) code in function cv::imencode
]
at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imencode_1(Native Method)
at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imencode(Highgui.java:243)
at Imshow.imshow(Imshow.java:29)
at test.main(Test.java:21)
```

Comment: The error output doesn't seem to correspond with the code in the question (there is no call to `imshow`). The path in the sample just seems to contain Basic Latin -- does that really reproduce the problem? | If you solved it, either write it in an answer, or just delete the question.

Comment: @DanMašek, I forget to say, the original file path looks like this: "E:/ℤIMAGEℂ/ℤtestℂ.png", with many Unicode Characters, and I didn't realize Unicode Characters resulted the error, so I wanted to ask this by a simpler code and have modified the path to "E:/IMAGE/test.png", but leading to a misleading effect of questioning. imshow is a pure image showing function, I forget to delete that info in console texts. I hope to hear from your result of this code.

Comment: If you solved the problem, then either answer the question yourself (if you think it can help someone else) or delete it

Comment: @leonbloy OK, I have posted one answer to explain what caused my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED & WHY**:

Path to image contains **Unicode character**.

As someone suggests if you solve your problem, delete it or answer it.

If you try to read image from Unicode path, errors occur, and I didn't see related solution, so you can read this.

*OpenCV is bugged with Unicode file path, sadly.* That's the problem of OpenCV but mine.